# How to refresh Partial View after confirm data row?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Ajax for load PartialView in Asp MVC4. But when I click confirm or delete, how to refresh data in PartialView and keep current page status?
This is Jquery:

```
$("button").click(function () {
            var weekno = [];
            $.each($(".selectpicker option:selected"), function () {
                weekno.push($(this).val());
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/PartialTable",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(weekno),
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (view) {
                    $('#viewpartial').html(view);
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert("Error! Please select Weekly No !!");
                }
            });
        });
```

Load PartialView Html:

```
<div id ="viewpartial" class="tab-content" style="overflow: scroll" </div>
```

PartialView is a Table

Confirm Action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Confirm", "Confirm", new { Action = "Confirm", fn = file.FILEID}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", id ="confirm" })

public ActionResult Confirm(Int32 fn) // fn is item ID
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var fname = me.MyTaBle.Where(f => f.FILEID.Equals(fn)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (fname.STATUS != null && fname.STATUS == "OPEN")
            {
                try
                {
                    fname.STATUS = "LOCK".ToString();
                    fname.CFMDATE = DateTime.Now;
                    me.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Error" + ex.Message.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        // **What's return in here??**
    }
```

I want to know what is return in Confirm action! Thank all

Comment: Is confirm method being called via ajax ? If not, what are you expecting to see after the Confirm method call ? Where is your cancel button ?

Comment: I'm not call confirm method via ajax, i use Html.Actionlink. After called the Confirm method, I want to refresh page, include keep PartialView.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not prefer to refresh your original page, you should do your confirm call via ajax.

Also,It is a good idea to put any code which updates your data behind a `HttpPost` action method to prevent people trying to execute your method via a browser with query string values.

So lets mark the  `Confirm` method with `HttpPost` attribute. You can return a json structure as the return value from the method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirm(Int fn)
{
  try
  { 
    // update your db record here
    return Json( new { status="success"});
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    //log the exception
   return Json( new { status="error"});
  }
}
```

Give an `id` to your link so that we can use that in our jQuery later.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Confirm", "Confirm","Home",
                                   new { fn = file.FILEID, new { id="confirmLink"})
```

And in your script, you can listen to the `click` event on this link and then make an ajax call to your action method. You can use the jQuery `post` method to do that.

```
$(function(){

   $("#confirmLink").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     _this=$(this);
     $.post(_this.attr("href"),function(res){
       if(res.status==="success")
       {
         alert("Updated successfully");
         //If you want to update some part of your page, you can do it here.
         //Ex : Getting the updated content from an ajax call and update UI
       }
       else
       {
         alert("Error updating");
       }
     });
   });

});
```

Comment: Thank, but RedirectToAction method not refresh page and keep my PartialView. PartialView i have called via Ajax, not include Index page.